# Remove duplicate entries and merge all column data in Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have Data in datatable like this.

```
id    antena  size  width  kpi1value kpi2value kpi3value erlvalue mbvalue kpi4value   
ab1     22     33    40      20                            22          
ab2     33     45    50      30                            30
ab3     11     40    60      20                            33
ab1     22     33    40                 55                           25
ab2     33     45    50                 30                           22
ab3     11     40    60                 20                           90
ab1     22     33    40                            40
ab2     33     45    50                            50
ab3     11     40    60                            20
ab1     22     33    40                                                         45
ab2     33     45    50                                                         55
ab3     11     40    60                                                         20
```

now, i have to arrange these data with common id. Like this

```
 id    antena  size  width  kpi1value kpi2value kpi3value erlvalue mbvalue kpi4value   
ab1     22     33    40      20         55        40         22        25    45
ab2     33     45    50      30         30        50         30        22    55
ab3     11     40    60      20         20        20         33        90    20
```

I tried to use the DefaultView for removing duplicates.

```
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true)
```

But, with this i was getting all the columns.

so, how can i arrange these data in datatable ?

Comment: Any effort so far? If so, show..

Comment: yes, i tried many alternates. but, didn't got any proper solution till now

Comment: Show your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: look my edited question.

Comment: Now can you answer ?  ---kumarch1

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no special method to gain effect you expect while it's hard to predict what user wants to do with non-unique data (etc., kpi1value, kpi2value).  I think you're lucky that programmers like the process of reinventing the wheel, so I wrote a bit code that might be used to accomplish your task.

### Code

```
public DataTable SpecialDistinct(DataTable table, 
    IList<string> uniqueFields, IList<string> otherFields)
{
    // create a table for results
    var resultTable = table.Clone();

    var view = new DataView(table);
    var distinctTable = view.ToTable(true, uniqueFields.ToArray());

    foreach (DataRow distictRow in distinctTable.Rows)
    {
        var row = resultTable.NewRow();
        foreach (var uniqueField in uniqueFields)
        {
            row[uniqueField] = distictRow[uniqueField];
        }

        IEnumerable<DataRow> selectedRows = table.AsEnumerable().Where(
            r => uniqueFields.All(
            uniqueField => r[uniqueField].Equals(distictRow[uniqueField])));

        foreach (var otherField in otherFields)
        {
            var selectedRow = selectedRows.FirstOrDefault(
                r => r[otherField] != DBNull.Value);
            if (selectedRow != null)
                row[otherField] = selectedRow[otherField];
        }
        resultTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return resultTable;
}
```

### Test

```
[TestMethod]
public void SpecialDistinctTest()
{
    // create a table
    var table = new DataTable();
    var uniqueFields = new List<string> { "ID", "antenna", "size" };
    var otherFields = new List<string> { "kpi1value", "kpi2value" };

    foreach (var uniqueField in uniqueFields)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(uniqueField, typeof(Int32)));
    }

    foreach (var otherField in otherFields)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(otherField, typeof(Int32)));
    }

    // add some items.
    AddRows(table);

    DataTable resultTable = SpecialDistinct(table, uniqueFields, otherFields);

    // check results from the table table
}

private void AddRows(DataTable table)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row.ItemArray = new object[] { 22, 33, 40, 20, DBNull.Value };
    table.Rows.Add(row);

    row = table.NewRow();
    row.ItemArray = new object[] { 33, 45, 50, 30, DBNull.Value };
    table.Rows.Add(row);

    row = table.NewRow();
    row.ItemArray = new object[] { 22, 33, 40, DBNull.Value, 55 };
    table.Rows.Add(row);

    row = table.NewRow();
    row.ItemArray = new object[] { 33, 45, 50, DBNull.Value, 30 };
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

### Results

**Original table**
[image]

**Result table**
[image]